# How to use a custom font in a Python visual in PowerBI

Tags: python, fonts, powerbi

I have written a Python script for a visual that I want to run as part of a PowerBI dashboard. The visual itself works, but I want to use my company's font (Euclid Flex). This font is not a standard font in matplotlib, so I would need to add it through the path to the ttf files on my computer. However, the font does exist in a theme in PowerBI, and of course when the dashboard gets published I can't refer to a local path to the ttf file. Is there any way I can set the font in matplotlib to Euclid Flex through PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by finding the font installation path no matter the user using `os.path.join(os.environ["LOCALAPPDATA"], "Microsoft/Windows/Fonts")`. If it can't find Euclid Flex here it will just switch to default.